# Getting CLASSPATH from environment in ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant, classpath, javac

How can I get the CLASSPATH from the environment in a build.xml?

I've tried

```
<property environment="env"/>

<path id="classpath">
  <pathelement location="${env.CLASSPATH}"/>
</path>

<target name="compile">
  <javac includeantruntime="false">
    <src path="${src}"/>
    <classpath refid="classpath"/>
  </javac>
</target>
```

I have a feeling this is failing because ${env.CLASSPATH} is a colon-separated list. 
How then, can I get my classpath? I was surprised when ant didn't use my environment's CLASSPATH.

EDIT:

I've found a quick solution, but the preferred method is to use a separate properties file like the example here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Ant/Useseparatepropertyfile.htm

Solution is, add

```
<property name="build.sysclasspath" value="first"/>
```

to the top of the build.xml

Comment: Why would you want it to? One of the points of an ant file is to have a portable build environment that explicitly *doesn't* rely on environment settings.

Comment: I want to do this because I'm using a version of junit which is stored in different locations on different machines on our network. I've relied on the environment CLASSPATH when using make.

Comment: That kind of information belongs in a user- or machine-specific properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's failing because it's a colon-separated list. In general, it's considered a bad idea to specify the class-path externally and use it within Ant. This is because running the same Ant script on different machines may yield different results. Instead, you're better of specifying the class-path from within Ant.